# Lumen: Auto increment and Reset Transaction_ID Automatically every month

Tags: laravel, lumen

I trying to generate random `transaction_id`, with format "2000-yymmm-0000".

I already know how to set the `transaction_id`, but I have a problem with the auto-increment from "2000-yymm-0000" to "2000-yymm-0001", and reseting automatically to "2000-yymm-0000" at every new month.

I put this logic in different path of controller.

PS: I'm using Lumen 6.0 with Laravel 6.0.

I'm trying to create the increment with:

```
$number = sprintf('%04d', 0000);
$number++;
```

but it didn't work.

```
$year = 2000;
$time = date('ym');
$number = sprintf('%04d', 0000);
$transaction_id = $year . '-' . $time . '-' . $number;
$transaction_data = explode('-', $transaction_id);
$month = date("m", strtotime($transaction_data[0]));
```

I expect the result to automatically increment every time a new data is stored to the database. But the actual result is `transaction_id` being having always the same value `2000-yymm-0000`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in your code, you never get the last transaction id, you create always the same. 1) get last transaction id wich looks like "2000-yymm-0001"           2) explode it in 4 parts with $parts=explode('-',$lastTransaction);           3) increment last part $parts[3]++ and format them with 0 filled,     4) rebuild the new id with implode ('-',$parts)

Comment: Hi @Eric, thank you for replying. i have been try your solution like $incrementId = $part[3]++;  , but i got error "Undefined offset: 3". do you have solution to solve this problem?

Comment: @Eric  do you have another solution to generate id like "2000-yymm-0000" in Laravel?

Comment: sorry, was $part[2]++ because explode return 3 parts, the [0], [1] and then the last part [2]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's weird to answer my own question, but i already find the solution.

in `Models/Order.php`
i create a function like this.

```
    public function count()
    {
     $this->where(transaction_id)->count();
    }
```

after that i call the function from `Model/Order.php` to `OrdersController.php`

```
    public function create(Request $request)
    {   

       $year = 2000;
       $date = date('ym');
       $total_data = $this->table->count();
       $number = str_pad($total_data + 1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
       $transaction_id = $year . '-' . $date . '-' . $number;

       return $this->success('count all transaction id', $t_id);
     }
```